# Redirecting from a dynamic URL to a prettier/simple URL?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I am trying to redirect a page via my .htaccess, but it does not seem to be working.

Old page:
/dyn/?q=customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1

New page:
/customer-references/

So it should be as simple as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=customer(?:[\ +]|%20)reference&f=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dyn/$ /1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But it does not seem to be working. Is it because the original page's dynamic URL?

The new page is actually a different physical php page if that matters.

BTW, I also tried a straight 301 Redirect in the .htaccess. That didn't seem to work either:

```
redirect 301 /dyn/?q=customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1 /customer-references/
```

And another failed attempt was this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/customer-references/? [R=301,L]
```

Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be?

Comment: Your RewriteRule replaces the URL which is dyn/ (nothing else). Try getting rid of the $ after dyn/

Comment: Removing the $ after dyn in the RewriteRule doesn't seem to do it. Can I hard code the "/?q=customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1" in the RewriteRule?

Comment: Not sure. Another problem is the $ after $f=1$ in RewriteCond. That means you only look for strings that end like that, and so won't match f=1,1,1,1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This did it, though I can't take credit for finding the solution on my own. Sister site stackoverflow offered up the proper code for .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=customer%20reference&f= [NC]
RewriteRule ^dyn/$ /customer-references/? [L,R=301]
```